# A formula $\varphi$ such that no "small" transitive $M$ will satisfy $M\preccurlyeq _\varphi V$.

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

This is exercise II.5.6 from Kunen's Set Theory:

> Assume Axiom of Choice. Find a formula $\varphi$ such that every transitive $M$ satisfying $M\preccurlyeq _\varphi V$ is of the form $R(\gamma)$ for some $\gamma = \beth _\gamma$.

(These $R(\gamma)$ are the "approximations of the universe" sometimes noted $V_\gamma$.)

It includes a hint:

> $\varphi$ can be $\varphi_{0}(x)$$\land$$\varphi_{1}$ where $\varphi_0(x)$ says that $x$ is the set of the form $R(\alpha)$, and $\varphi_1$ is a sentence and a theorem of $ZFC$.

I imagine Kunen meant to write "where $\varphi_0(x)$ says that $x$ is $\textbf{a}$ set of the form $R(\alpha)$" but I copy it here verbatim just in case.

I don't get this hint, it seems to say $\varphi_1$ can be any theorem of $ZFC$ but this doesn't make sense as taking $\varphi_1$ to be $\exists z (z=z)$ we get $R(\omega)\preccurlyeq_\varphi V$ as for every $x\in R(\omega)$ we have $\varphi_0(x) ^{R(\omega)} \iff \varphi_0(x) ^{V}$. But $\omega \neq \beth_\omega$.

Am I misinterpreting the hint? I need help solving this exercise. Thank you for reading.

P.S. This exercise is probably related to the Reflection Theorem as it is given in the chapter dedicated to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that if $\varphi=\varphi_0(x)\wedge\varphi_1$ for $\varphi_1$ a theorem of ZFC, then $M\preccurlyeq_\varphi V$ iff

- $M\preccurlyeq_{\varphi_0}V$, and
- $M\models \varphi_1$.

So we're really getting to constrain $M$ in two ways: $M$ will be *correct* about $\varphi_0$, and $M$ will *satisfy* $\varphi_1$.

For example, take $\varphi_0(x)=$"$x=\langle y, z\rangle$ for some $y, z$ such that $y=\mathcal{P}(z)$" and $\varphi_1$ to be a large finite fragment of ZFC containing the Powerset axiom. Then $M\preccurlyeq_{\varphi}V$ implies that $M$ is closed under powersets: the $\varphi_1$-part says that $M$ contains "internal powersets" - that is, for each $z\in M$ there is some $y\in M$ such that $M$ thinks $y$ is the powerset of $z$ - and the $\varphi_0$-part implies that the "internal powersets" are in fact *actual* powersets.

Does this help?

Comment: Ok I get the strategy, thank you. Very valuable answer. But will precisely these $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_1$ work for my purpose? (I'd like to know before I start trying to fill in the details.) Also, I don't see where transitivity of $M$ is being used.

Comment: The $\varphi_i$s I've written down will *not* work for your problem - $V_\lambda$ satisfies them for any limit ordinal $\lambda$.

Comment: I've been thinking for this last hour and haven't gotten it yet, I have trouble "giving shape" to this $M$. If I assume there exists $\gamma$ such that $M=R(\beth_\gamma)$, I can use the formulas $\varphi_0 (x,y) : x =\beth_y$ and $\varphi_1 : \forall y\in On \exists \beth_y$ and get the result $\beth_\gamma = \gamma$. But I can't prove $M=R(\beth_\gamma)$. Could you help me with a new hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mingus HINT: $M=R(\beth_\gamma)$ iff (i) $M=R(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$, and $(ii)$ for each ordinal $\alpha\in M$ we have $\beth_\alpha\in M$ as well. Now, if $M$ is correct about powersets and satisfies the powerset axiom, then $M=R(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$ (do you see why?). So all that's left is to fold (ii) in . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber, perhaps this might help  http://math.stackexchange.com/a/563458/

Comment: @NoahSchweber Are you sure satisfying power set and being right about it is enough to get $M=R(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$? I've been trying and I can't get neither inclusion. I feel so inept. I just need to get $M=R(\alpha)$, I'm confident with the rest of my solution.

Comment: @Mingus I was too fast - you need "a large enough fragment of ZFC". The idea is to show by induction that for every ordinal $\beta$, if $M$ contains *some* set of rank $\beta$ then it contains *all* sets of rank $\beta$. You'll use powerset for successor $\beta$s and some more ZFC for the limit $\beta$s. (Remember that $M$ is also assumed to be transitive.)